# Sketching in the $(r,\theta)$ plane

Tags: polar-coordinates

Considering the integral

$ \int\int_R x^2log(x^2+y^2)dxdy $ where $R$ is the annulus $1\leq x^2+y^2\leq 2$.

Change the variables to polar coordinates and sketch the region $R$ in the $(x,y)$ plane and also the corresponding region in the $(r,\theta)$ plane.

So after changing the variables I find the integral turns in to:

$\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{2}_1r^3cos\theta log(r^2)drd\theta$.

However when it comes to sketching I am confused, in the $x,y$ plane I can see our region is a donut shape enclosed between two discs. However how can I sketch the corresponding region?

Based on searching online I found that the region turns in to $1\leq r \leq \sqrt2$ and $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

What does this even mean however, what region should I be sketching/looking for?

Comment: You got it: in the $(r,\theta)$ plane, the region is a rectangle of dimensions $\sqrt{2}\times 2\pi$

Comment: @RafaBudría could you explain to me how you can see that please?

Comment: Consider the usual $x$ $y$ plane and rename the $x$ axis as $r$ and the $y$ axis as $\theta$, this is the $(r,\theta)$ plane. in this plane, the values for $r$ and $\theta$ form a rectangle.

Comment: @RafaBudría I think I understand now, but if it is how I think, should the dimensions not be $(\sqrt{2}-1)$x$2\pi$ ? As my $r$ is $1 \leq r \leq \sqrt{2} $ and not $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{2} $.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the dimensions are these you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the bounds right for the integral when you've transformed it, so just look at those bounds. They are numbers, not variables, so that means your variable goes from one constant to another constant. Since that happens for both variables, the region is called rectangular.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. From
$$
x=r\cos \theta,\quad y=r\sin \theta,
$$ one gets
$$
x^2+y^2=r^2(\cos^2 \theta+\sin \theta^2)=r^2 \cdot 1
$$ then
$$
1\le x^2+y^2 \le 2
$$ reads $1\le r^2 \le 2$ that is
$$
1\le r \le \sqrt{2}
$$ since $r\ge0$.

One thus obtains
$$
\begin{align}
\int\int_R x^2\log(x^2+y^2)dxdy&=2\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{\sqrt{2}}_1r^3\cos^2\theta \log(r)dr\:d\theta
\\&=2\left(\int^{2\pi}_0\cos^2\theta \:d\theta\right)\left(\int^{\sqrt{2}}_1r^3\log(r)dr\right)
\end{align}
$$ Can you finish it?

Comment: I do understand this part, it's the sketching I am having trouble with!

Comment: @N.K Please, I don't understand what do you mean by "the sketching"...

Comment: I guess it is a case of struggling with the simpler part of the question. I am just unsure how to visualise the region I will find when it is in the $r,\theta $ plane.

Comment: @N.K Ok, concerning $\theta$ we have $0\le \theta \le 2 \pi$ since $(x,y)$ varies in the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$... For example, if we had $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R}^+$ then $\theta$ would be such that $0\le \theta \le \pi/2$...

Comment: @N.K This can be somewhat enlightining: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolarCoordinates.html